# Calendly web hook POST request getting bounce by wwwhisper authetication

Tags: express, heroku, calendly, wwwhisper

I've been trying to figure out how to get a web hook subscription from calendly.com to work with my heroku deployed, wwwhisper protected site (https://elements.heroku.com/addons/wwwhisper). From what I understand, I needed to upgrade to a 'team' plan for that too work. I've done that and also added https://calendly.com to my list of allowed addresses on wwwhisper's admin ui, but all of the POST requests from calendly continue to get bounced with a 401. Am I missing something? It's all running on an Express server and working just fine locally. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

adding my POST route for the calendly hook along with a * in the 'enter an email to grant access' field on wwwhispers access control page did the trick